# TYPO3 typo3_forum menu doesn't work

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18 and I installed typo3_forum 1.1. The problem is that menu doesn't show, I learned problem and I see that ajax request sending to ajaxAction and get menu and it must be putted to html by js. I see that I receive empty data, therefor posting form is absent and other too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in ajaxController. I don't know why but js was send wrong json format. I edit little bit main action.

```
public function mainAction($displayedUser = "", $postSummarys = "", $topicIcons = "", $forumIcons = "", $displayedTopics = "", $displayOnlinebox = 0, $displayedPosts = "", $displayedForumMenus = "", $displayedAds = "") {
            // json array

        $content = [];

        if (!empty($_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['displayedUser'])) {
            $displayedUser = str_replace('"', '', $_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['displayedUser']);
            $content['onlineUser'] = $this->_getOnlineUser($displayedUser);
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['displayedForumMenus'])) {
            $displayedForumMenus = str_replace('"', '', $_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['displayedForumMenus']);
            $content['forumMenus'] = $this->_getForumMenus($displayedForumMenus);
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['postSummarys'])) {
            $postSummarys = str_replace('"', '', $_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['postSummarys']);
            $content['postSummarys'] = $this->_getPostSummarys($postSummarys);
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['topicIcons'])) {
            $topicIcons = str_replace('"', '', $_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['topicIcons']);
            $content['topicIcons'] = $this->_getTopicIcons($topicIcons);
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['forumIcons'])) {
            $forumIcons = str_replace('"', '', $_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['forumIcons']);
            $content['forumIcons'] = $this->_getForumIcons($forumIcons);
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['displayedTopics'])) {
            $displayedTopics = str_replace('"', '', $_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['displayedTopics']);
            $content['topics'] = $this->_getTopics($displayedTopics);
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['displayedPosts'])) {
            $displayedPosts = str_replace('"', '', $_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['displayedPosts']);
            $content['posts'] = $this->_getPosts($displayedPosts);
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['displayedPosts'])) {
            $displayedPosts = str_replace('"', '', $_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['displayedPosts']);
            $content['posts'] = $this->_getPosts($displayedPosts);
        }
        if ($displayOnlinebox == 1) {
            $content['onlineBox'] = $this->_getOnlinebox();
        }
        $displayedAds = json_decode($_POST['tx_typo3forum_ajax']['displayedAds']);
        if ((int)$displayedAds->count > 1) {
            $content['ads'] = $this->_getAds($displayedAds);
        }

        $this->view->assign('content', json_encode($content));
    }
```

Comment: See https://github.com/mittwald/typo3_forum. Maybe there is a issue or pull request compare to your problem - otherwise create one